# How to pass model data inside foreach loop to views using laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-views

I have a foreach loop where each time certain value is matched and then it related records is fetched

```
 foreach($results as $result){
    // Value may be 1,2,3 etc
    if($result->id == $value){
       $users = User::whereId($value)->get();
    }
  }
  return view('index',compact('users'));
```

Now how to pass all users records to the view?
Currently it only fetches the first record!

Answer (score 1):

You can store all id's in an array and then fetch all records at once. Running a database queries in a loop have a **performance overhead**.

```
$userIds = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    // Value may be 1, 2, 3 etc.
    if ($result->id == $value){
        $userIds[] = $value;
    }
}

$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();

return view('index', compact('users'));
```

Comment: Perhaps you doesn't get my question,i don't all records,only that records that are matched with specific condition in loop.Please review the question,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use "whereIn" for this purpose.

You can get further information from  [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

```
$ids = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {

    if ($result->id == $value){
        $ids[] = $value;
    }
}

$users = User::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

return view('index', compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is:

- Make a new array that holds arrays of users when it matches
- Then return that new array

Example:

```
$matchedUsers = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    // Value may be 1,2,3 etc
    if($result->id == $value) {
       $matchedUsers[] = User::whereId($value)->get();
    }
}
return view('index', compact('matchedUsers'));
```

An even cleaner way to do this is to have a seperate function that does your call for User Info when it matches:

```
public function getUsers($results)
{
    $matchedUsers = array();

    foreach($results as $result){
        // Value may be 1,2,3 etc
        if($result->id == $value) {
            $matchedUsers[] = User::whereId($value)->get();
        }
    }
    return view('index', compact('matchedUsers'));
}

public function getMatchedUser($userId)
{
    return User::whereId($userId)->get();
}
```